# Keyboard shortcut for “Global Search” in Thunderbird 3.0 (Windows)

Tags: email, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, search

Is there any keyboard shortcut to change the search criteria (like Subject, To, From, Message Body etc.) of the [Global Search](http://support.mozillamessaging.com/id/kb/Global+Search)

I know that when in TB you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to get Global Search in focus, but if you want to change the criteria from "message body" to lets say "from", can we do that from keyboard.

If there isn't exits one, can it be configured ?

Comment: I have re-posted this question here, earlier posted on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/keyboard-shortcut-for-global-search-in-thunderbird-3-0-windows